# On the Princeton Lectures

Tags: analysis, reference-works

I've heard nothing but good things about the [Princeton Lectures in Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Lectures_in_Analysis) and was looking to start reading them.  I just have a question for anyone who's read them before.  Do they have to be read in order to be understood?  I ask because I'm least interested in the first book on Fourier Analysis and most interested in looking at their third book on Real Analysis/ Measure Theory.  So I was wondering if I could skip book 1 and maybe even book 2 and come back to them later.  Am I going to be completely lost if I do that?  I'd rather just buy the books one at a time so it'd be good to know beforehand if I can just buy book 2 or 3 right now or if I should just start with book 1.  For reference I have only taken one course in analysis and it was real analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The books, and the course sequence from which they arose, are intended to show the extensive links between the different topic areas.

Even so, as the Introduction to Book 3, *Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces* explains,

> Despite the substantial connections that exist between the different volumes, enough overlapping material has been provided so that each of the first three books requires only minimal prerequisites...

**Moral of the story:** Mathematics texts usually do a good job in their introductions explaining their intended audiences and are well worth reading!

Comment: Oh OK.  Thanks! :)